# If a column contains a certain term

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to search Table, for data where the Id column matches the search query. This is only my second day with SQL so Im having some issues.

This is what I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE Id LIKE '%@search%'
```

This doesnt work, how should I go about this?
Thanks!

Comment: do you mean `'%' + @search + '%'`?

Comment: also if its a exact match use WHERE ID='" + @search + "'

Comment: Thanks a lot, that as exactly what I needed! And thanks for that Frank_VR, Im not looking for exact matches but that will come in handy in the future. Cheers

Comment: What do your ids look like?  Note that if these are numeric auto-number ids, the value is essentially meaningless...

Answer (score 3):

If your implementation is in SQL Server, following should be the format should be:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE Id LIKE '%' + @search + '%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
'%@search%'
```

To

```
'%' + @search + '%'
```